# Updating ManyToMany jointable in Java

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many, relationship, entities

I generated Entities and Facades using netbeans. Below is an example that works/updates:

I have 2 tables that are joined by a join table where it works:

### User

PK: userID

### Category

PK: categoryID

### User_Category

Composite PK: userID | categoryID
(no other columns)

Method to update join table, taking care of relationships on both sides:

```
    //set up user Categories
    List<Category> categoryList = new ArrayList<Category>();

    //get all the current categories for the current user
    categoryList.addAll(user.getCategoryList());

    //clear out user for that type (to reset)
    for(Category c : categoryList){
        tempUserList.clear();
        tempUserList = c.getUserList();
        tempUserList.remove(user);
        c.setUserList(tempUserList);
        categoryFacade.edit(c);
    }

    categoryList.clear();
    //where selectedCategoryListString is a list of category names
    for(String s : selectedCategoryListString){
        categoryList.add(categoryFacade.findByCategoryName(s));
    }

    for(Category c : categoryList){
        tempUserList.clear();
        tempUserList = c.getUserList();
        tempUserList.add(user);
        c.setUserList(tempUserList);
        categoryFacade.edit(c);
    }
    user.setCategoryList(categoryList);
    userFacade.edit(user);
```

The above works, it takes care of both sides of the relationship. Where I'm stuck is below. A 'skill' does not have the method '.getUserList()' because of the extra 'years' column. Instead, it has a '.getUserSkillList()'. I am lost as to how I should be updating the join table like I did above. We can assume that the 'years' column gets set to "" (blank) every time.

Below: problematic tables/relationship:

### User

userID

### Skill

skillID

### UserSkill

userID | skillID | years

What's important is: User has a userID. Skill has a skillID, UserSkill has a composite primary key made up of userID and skillID and the other column; years.

Comment: You are using hibernate, right?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified: EclipseLink

Answer (score 0):

If you were using hibernate, that issue would be resolved by simply adding a `Cascade.UPDATE` over the `UserSkill` property of class `User`.

However, as you are not using hibernate, you can have it done manually. When updating a `User`, retrieve those `UserSkills` related to it and update them as well.

*if you have any specific problem in doing that, let me know to update my answer*

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure without seeing your entity classes but you might be looking for something like:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, ...)
```

[CascadeType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html)